# Lumen: how to pass parameters to controller from route

Tags: laravel, lumen

from my route i need to pass the value of $page to controller

route:

```
$app->get('/show/{page}', function($page) use ($app) {

  $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\PageController');
  return $controller->index();

});
```

controller:

```
public static function index(){

  /** how can I get the value of $page form here so i can pass it to the view **/

  return view('index')->with('page', $page);

}
```

Comment: pass it to the controllers method as a parameter `index($page)`

Comment: i've already done it! but thanks for this i've  figured it out the real problem with this error `Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\PageController::index() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::index()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could pass it as a parameter of the index function.

**Route**

```
$app->get('/show/{page}', function($page) use ($app) {
    $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\PageController');
    return $controller->index( $page );
});
```

Although the route looks wrong to me, normally you define the route without a forward slash at the beggining:  `$app->get('show/{page}', ...`.

**Controller**

```
public static function index($page)
{
    return view('index')->with('page', $page);
}
```

Unless there is a reason for using a closure, your route could be re-written as below, and the `{$page}` variable will automatically be passed to the controller method as a parameter:

**Route**

```
$app->get('show/{page}', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@index'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, showing specified user, it's pretty much the same case

**route file** (web.php)

```
Route::get('user/{id}/show', ['as'=> 'show', 'uses'=>'UserController@show']);
```

> im still using facade

**view file** (users.blade.php)

```
href="{{route('show', ['id' => $user->id])}}"
```

just passing an array to route name
and the last one in

**controller file**(UserController.php)

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::findorfail($id)->first();
        return view('user', compact('user'));
    }
```

it's done